# Why does my flyback give me 1.5 output voltage

Tags: flyback

Here is my flyback circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUgdjE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ZCD circuit isn't represent because I didn't find auxiliary SMPS in the list of components. Can someone helps me, thank you. PFC :

The optocoupler doesn't leave current from Vcc because the TL431 cut the circuit (Vref << 2.5V.)

The PFC sometimes lets the current pass through the MOSFET but not enough to have 24V on the output and trigger the control of the circuit.

I have 1.5 V in the output after 5min when I plug the circuit.
[image]
Comp is in Yellow
Vcc in blue

[image]

Cs is in Yellow
ZCD in blue
PFC : https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6562a.pdf
OPTOCOUPLER: https://docs.rs-online.com/6b56/0900766b80083e16.pdf

Comment: Designing a flyback converter using a boost PFC controller is a bit challenging. You may want to take a look at [this app note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an3424-stevalill042v1-high-power-factor-flyback-led-driver-based-on-the-l6562a-and-tsm101-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

Comment: Please show COMP, Vcc, ZCD and CS waveforms.

Comment: Thank you I have already looked at it, ok I will post images of these pins

Comment: because you forgot to connect the other end of the right side of the transformer to anything useful?

Comment: Where is the primary flyback snubber ?

Comment: The snubber isn't necessary but usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CS was too high, as CS determine the current peak, Ipeak = 1V/R = 0.5A, the current was too low.
I replace the 2 ohms resistance by 0.5 ohms and it works, thanks for all response .

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the (-) side of the isolated output connected to the TL431, so there is no feedback.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: I don't know which - side you mean, have you an exemple ?

Comment: @kodi what is the bottom right pin of the transformer doing?

Comment: Ok thank you, I just forgot it in the schema

Answer (score 0):

That's not a flyback, you have the transformer or diode backwards.

Also the ground connection is missing on the secondary.